# LiveReload for Sublime Text 3 was removed

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, livereload, package-control

I want to install LiveReload for Sublime Text 3. However, when I go to Package Control to install, I realize that LiveReload is no longer there.

When I visit this website: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LiveReload, it shows that "Package was removed and no longer available".

The github repository: https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2/tree/devel is also unavailable.

Are there anyway to install LiveReload for Sublime Text 3? This is a very cool feature and I just don't want to abandon it.

Comment: Do you still have it on Sublime Text 2? If you do I can post how to transfer it

Comment: No, I used to use it with Sublime Text 3. But I reset everything so now I need a new installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted an archive of the plugin as it was in October 2014. It's [available on Github](https://github.com/MattDMo/LiveReload-archive). Please note that I have zero interest at this time in maintaining it, I posted it solely as a public service. If you would like to take over *actively* maintaining the project, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I have just forked this repository. Still don't know why they removed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new sublime text plugin [`LiveReload`](https://github.com/alepez/LiveReload-sublimetext3) available. You can use it to replace the the original LiveReload plugin.